# How to escape quotes & (semi)colons in tmux bind-key?

Tags: tmux, key-binding, escape-characters

I'd like to do something like this

```
bind-key -T root ' <some-command>
bind-key -T root " <some-command>
bind-key -T root : <some-command>
bind-key -T root ; <some-command>

# or with alt
bind-key -T root M-' <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-" <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-: <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-; <some-command>

# or with control
bind-key -T root C-' <some-command>
bind-key -T root C-" <some-command>
bind-key -T root C-: <some-command>
bind-key -T root C-; <some-command>

# or with alt & control
bind-key -T root M-C-' <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-C-" <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-C-: <some-command>
bind-key -T root M-C-; <some-command>
```

What of these are possible?

Is there a tool which gets pressed keys and gives ascii representation ready to use in `bind-key`. Something like vim Control-v in command mode (:).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do these bindings:

```
bind-key -T root '"' send-keys ' dblquot'
bind-key -T root "'" send-keys ' quot'
bind-key -T root :   send-keys ' colon'
bind-key -T root \;  send-keys ' semicolon'
```

and their Meta prefix versions:

```
bind-key -T root 'M-"' send-keys ' Mdblquot'
bind-key -T root "M-'" send-keys ' Mquot'
bind-key -T root M-:   send-keys ' Mcolon'
bind-key -T root M-\;  send-keys ' Msemicolon'
```

and test them, but a terminal emulator is not able to apply Control to characters outside the ascii range `@` to `_` (i.e. a to z plus  `@[\]^_`), so you cannot type <kbd>Control-'</kbd> and so on, nor their Meta-Control versions.

Comment: _a terminal emulator is not able to apply Control to characters outside the ascii range `@` to `_`_ ... so that's why! Any workaround or do we simply have to give up on `M-\;`?

Comment: A terminal emulator might provide, for example, a lower-level access to the X11 raw keycodes and current status of the Control and Meta shift keys, and allow you to convert that combination into a single unicode character, or a sequence of characters. If you are using a particular emulator you could try posting a question on unix.stackexchange.com giving details on it and the graphics server (X11 or wayland etc) you want to use.